# services accessing a secret store

Tags: hashicorp-vault, key-storage

I'm trying to understand the interactions between humans, services, and secret stores. I've been looking at HashiCorp Vault documentation and tutorial to try and get a better understanding. I'm using Vault instead of the more cumbersome 'secret store' below:

The use case is when a service needs to access Vault to get a secret (such as db connection string). It seems like the human that configures the service with the credentials to access Vault would also know those credentials and can impersonate that service at any time.

On the other hand, if Vault was also the identity provider for the service, it could provide one-time-use initial credentials to be used during service initialization. Then, these are rotated out. At that point, a human cannot impersonate the service they set up during 'normal operation'.

However, I haven't read this use case in the documentation, so I'm confused.

To add clarity, I understand that eventually someone must be trusted. For example, the ops engineer can have his *own* credentials to access Vault and get a password for the same database. This would allow the user access, but not allow that user to impersonate the service. Is there any reason that the ops engineer should also know the service's own credentials to access Vault after the initialization?

Answer (score 1):

Vault supports creating one time use credentials for several services, mostly databases - see the [Secret Backend](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/index.html) section of the docs.

The mysql backend includes the following description:

> Additionally, it introduces a new ability: with every service accessing the database with unique credentials, it makes auditing much easier when questionable data access is discovered: you can track it down to the specific instance of a service based on the SQL username.

Comment: So that part I understand, but what about the application service you write that wants to get the mysql credentials _from_Vault? If you are configuring that, aren't you then able to ask Vault for a mysql credential anytime, impersonating your application service?

Comment: There are lots of best practices - like not having active root keys when not required, using AppRole to split the login between developers and admins - but, ultimately, if you don't trust yourself as the person setting it all up, I'm not sure Vault can save you from yourself.

Comment: At some point certainly someone in the company should be trusted, but it seems like the shamir key sharding would be the ideal approach to apply to these root keys too. Otherwise, are you protecting yourself from internal breaches in any way, if the access key is known?